# Javascript check box to uncheck other boxes and vice versa

Tags: javascript

I have the following set of checkboxes:

```
Original:
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" ID="db1" class="db" checked>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" ID="db2" class="db" checked>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" ID="db3" class="db" checked>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" ID="db4" class="db" checked>

</br>

Other:
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" ID="other" class="other" onclick="otherBoxes('other',this)">
```

and the following javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function otherBoxes(it,box)
  {
    $(function()
      {
        $(':checkbox').click(function()
          {
            if (this.checked) 
              {
                $('.db').prop('checked',false);
              }
          }
        )
      }
    )
  }
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is set someting up so that when I check the 'other' checkbox, the 'Original' checkboxes are all unchecked.
I then want to have the reverse, so that if one (or more) of the 'Original' checkboxes are checked, the 'other' checkbox is unchecked.

The Javascript I have so far kind of does the first part of this, in that if I check, then uncheck, then check the 'other' box again, the 'Original' boxes are unchecked. 
However, I would like it to work when the box is checked the first time.

It also has the unintended consequence, that after the 'other' box has been checked, the 'original' boxes refuse to be checked, even if I uncheck the 'other' box.

I've found lots of examples of similar situations, but none the same, and I haven't been able to adapt any that I have found. How can I do this please?

Comment: You have jQuery code there, is a jQuery solution acceptable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like that

```
$('.other').on('click' , function() {
 $('.db').each(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
 })
});

$('.db').on('click', function(){
    $('.other').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

here it is a working **jsfiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/vQTFm/

P.S. : I suggest you to avoid using similar names beetwen `id`s and `class`s because it CAN be confusing.

Comment: thanks for the response. That worked liked a charm. The only thing I had to change was to add: $(window).load(function(){ to the begining of it.

Answer (score 1):

You should bind the events using jQuery instead of in the HTML.

Here is some code that does what you want, it binds to the change event on the checkboxes and then checks whether it was the `other` or `db` checkboxes that were checked and unchecks the required check-boxes:

```
$(function() {
    $('.db, #other').on('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            if ($(this).is('#other')) {
                $('input:checkbox').not('#other').prop('checked', false);
            } else {
                $('#other').prop('checked', false);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/YD5SE/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function otherBoxes(it,box)
  {
     if (box.checked) 
      {
          $('.db').prop('checked',false);
      }
  }
    </script>
```